# syntax error in from clause in nested joins in an ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am getting a Syntax Error in FROM Clause dialog box when I try to run the following query in MS-Access 2010:

```
SELECT 
    Contact_addresses.AddressID, 
    Contact_addresses.ContactID, 
    Contact_addresses.Address1, 
    Contact_addresses.Address2, 
    Contact_addresses.City, 
    Contact_addresses.State, 
    Contact_addresses.Zip, 
    Owner_Operator.FIRM_NAME, 
    Official_Correspondent.FIRST_NAME, 
    Official_Correspondent.LAST_NAME, 
    Official_Correspondent.SUBACCOUNT_COMPANY_NAME, 
    Official_Correspondent.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM Contact_addresses 
    (
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT
                Owner_Operator.CONTACT_ID, 
                Owner_Operator.FIRM_NAME 
                FROM Owner_Operator) 
            ON Contact_addresses.ContactID=Owner_Operator.CONTACT_ID
        ) 
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT 
                Official_Correspondent.CONTACT_ID, 
                Official_Correspondent.FIRST_NAME, 
                Official_Correspondent.LAST_NAME, 
                Official_Correspondent.SUBACCOUNT_COMPANY_NAME,
                Official_Correspondent.PHONE_NUMBER 
                FROM Official_Correspondent) 
            ON Contact_addresses.ContactID=Official_Correspondent.CONTACT_ID
        ;
```

When I dismiss the dialog box, access highlights the ( after FROM Contact_addresses.

I know that I need parentheses with multiple nested joins in Access, but can someone please explain the concepts of how this works, in addition to showing how to fix whatever the problem is?

The relevant aspects of the schema of the underlying tables should be clear from the SQL SELECT statements.

Comment: In general, you should have a Table alias for each sub query involved in the join. i.e `(Select ...) As X Left join (Select ...) AS Y`

Comment: Your brackets are a bit screwy.  it should look as : from (table or query) left join (table or qry) on col=col.   The bracket set between the from contact_addresses and the left join shouldn't be there.  (the table alias comment aboe should also be noted).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work, but I lack access to test.  General syntax to hold to

From table
left join (statement) alias
on table.col = alias.col
left join ...

Altering your statement to this:

```
FROM Contact_addresses 

    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT
            Owner_Operator.CONTACT_ID, 
            Owner_Operator.FIRM_NAME 
            FROM Owner_Operator)   Owner_Operator
        ON Contact_addresses.ContactID=Owner_Operator.CONTACT_ID

    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            Official_Correspondent.CONTACT_ID, 
            Official_Correspondent.FIRST_NAME, 
            Official_Correspondent.LAST_NAME, 
            Official_Correspondent.SUBACCOUNT_COMPANY_NAME,
            Official_Correspondent.PHONE_NUMBER 
            FROM Official_Correspondent)  Official_Correspondent
        ON Contact_addresses.ContactID=Official_Correspondent.CONTACT_ID
    ;
```

I've added the table alias to match what you call it in your join and I removed the offending set of brackets.

Comment: +1 for trying to help.  Thank you.  I tried your changes and it is now throwing "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Contact_addresses.ContactID=Owner_Operator.CONTACT_ID ... (to the end of the query)'".  Any more ideas?

Comment: I fixed the problem.  See my answer that I just posted along with yours. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the location of the opening brackets ((.  They need to be immediately after the first FROM.  Here is what works:

```
SELECT Contact_addresses.AddressID, Contact_addresses.ContactID, Contact_addresses.Address1, Contact_addresses.Address2, Contact_addresses.City, Contact_addresses.State, Contact_addresses.Zip, Owner_Operator.FIRM_NAME, Official_Correspondent.FIRST_NAME, Official_Correspondent.LAST_NAME, Official_Correspondent.SUBACCOUNT_COMPANY_NAME, Official_Correspondent.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM ((Contact_addresses 

        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT 
                Owner_Operator.CONTACT_ID, 
                Owner_Operator.FIRM_NAME 
                FROM Owner_Operator) AS Owner_Operator 
            ON Contact_addresses.ContactID=Owner_Operator.CONTACT_ID 
)
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT 
                Official_Correspondent.CONTACT_ID, 
                Official_Correspondent.FIRST_NAME, 
                Official_Correspondent.LAST_NAME, 
                Official_Correspondent.SUBACCOUNT_COMPANY_NAME, 
                Official_Correspondent.PHONE_NUMBER 
                FROM Official_Correspondent) AS Official_Correspondent 
            ON Contact_addresses.ContactID=Official_Correspondent.CONTACT_ID 
)        
;
```

Comment: Good solve...Access is a screwy implement of SQL and relies on very unique SQL syntax.